# Set Value of Hidden Field in SharePoint using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint

I am able to set the value of a site column (field), using jQuery, when it is not hidden using this:

```
    $("select[Title='MyID']").val(MyRelatedID);
```

However, once I hide the field it doesn't work. I inspected the code and it looks like SharePoint hides it from the source code as well. I am opening the list containing the fields in a modal. Has anyone be able to set the hidden value of field?

Comment: jQuery can't act on an element that doesn't exist in the DOM.

Comment: That's my concern, I was hoping that I just missed it in the source as SharePoint can do some "interesting" things. Maybe I can take off the hidden view in SharePoint to get it in the DOM then hide it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually use this approach:

To set the value:

```
$('input[title="MyID"]').attr("value",MyRelatedID);
```

To hide the field:

```
$('input[title="MyID"]').parent().parent().parent().css("display","none");
```

I documented the complete approach [here](http://surpoint.blogspot.com/2013/12/relaciones-de-maestro-detalle-en.html).